# Persistent connection between RRAS servers?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, vpn, windows-server-2008-r2, rras

I currently have a Server 2008 server at the office and a Server 2008 R2 server at a Data Center.  Both have RRAS installed for PPTP VPN access.

The office server is behind a router, is there a way to have the office RRAS server (or router) connect persistently to the Data Center VPN server so I can create a trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [persistent demand-dial connections](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771337(WS.10).aspx) for Routing and Remote Access Service )(RRAS). Beware that installing RRAS on a domain controller will make it multihomed (which can introduce fun minor issues-- RAS adapter being registered in DNS, NetBIOS master browser hijinks) and Microsoft recommends against multihoming domain controllers.